# Objective-C delegate incompatible type

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pdf

I am using http://www.vfr.org/, pdf viewer, and I try to add a button to open PDF in IBOOK.

I added the button and action to it, but I stuck t the moment when I want open ibooks application with this pdf.

I tried 2 solutions:

1. button tapped action:

   ```
   NSURL *fileURL = document.fileURL;
   NSString *fileName = document.fileName; // Document
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:fileURL];
   ```

It opens the IBOOKS but the PDF never gets loaded.

I am assuming the URL format can be wrong I tried even hard code a PDF URL like:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"itms-books://linktopdf.pdf";     
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

But the same result.

2) Button tapped action:

```
    NSURL *fileURL = document.fileURL;
    NSString *fileName = document.fileName; // Document
    UIDocumentInteractionController *docController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];
    docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
    docController.delegate = self;
```

But I have an warning where I try to delegate:  `docController.delegate = self;`

*`assigning to id UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate from Incompatible ReaderViewController`*

Can someone help me to make it work at least 1 of these solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has the *ReaderViewController* this kind of line in the header file: `@interface ReaderViewController : NSObject < UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate >` ?

Comment: And I MOVED my var name in @interface, but I think that is not right

Comment: I still don't see the `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` between the *< ... >*. It should be like this: `@interface ReaderViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate,  UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate,                       ReaderMainToolbarDelegate, ReaderMainPagebarDelegate, ReaderContentViewDelegate, ThumbsViewControllerDelegate, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>`

Comment: Larme, it help the warning, and I have no issue, but the ibook still doesn't get opened. Pretty much no action happening :(

Comment: Not changing what I suggested and your code would never go through the delegate methods. That was what meant the warning. Anyway, does it work now? I guess going through the delegate methods help you debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Your class must conform to the `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate`  protocol, so in your **.h file** make it look like

```
@interface ReaderViewController : PerantClass <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>
{

...

}
```

Then the compiler will know that your class conforms to that protocol. Of course, you still need to implement the needed methods.

ALso Check this [Link - 1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) And [Link - 2.](http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html)